# Mysql always 0 results if no data found in JOIN tables when data found in another table?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I am having a problem with the sql below. It seems the query returns 0 results if nothing is found when joining tables group_permissions & users_permissions even though something is found in users.

```
SELECT `*` 
  FROM (`users`) 
  LEFT JOIN `group_permissions` ON `users`.`group_id` = `group_permissions`.`group_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `users_permissions` ON `users`.`user_id` = `users_permissions`.`user_id` 
 WHERE `users`.`username` = 'admin'
```

I can't seem to figure out how to fix so it would still return data from users even when nothing was found in tables group_permissions & users_permissions.

**UPDATED**

Ok I have changed to LEFT JOIN now my problem is the columns user_id and group_id in table users is overwritten by the ones from group_permissions & users_permissions resulting in value being NULL.

How can I fix this? Is there anyway to alter the JOIN so it doesn't fetch those columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ok I have changed to `LEFT JOIN` now my problem is the columns user_id and group_id in table users is overwritten by the ones from group_permissions & users_permissions resulting in value being NULL.

Your query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users
LEFT JOIN
        group_permissions
ON      group_permissions.group_id = users.group_id
LEFT JOIN
        users_permissions
ON      users_permissions.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE   users.username = 'admin'
```

will return all fields from all three tables.

It won't "overwrite" anything, rather it will return two fields named `user_id` and two fields named `group_id`: those belonging to `users` and those belonging to the respective tables.

It may confuse the client, especially if you use an associative array to access the fields (like `mysql_fetch_assoc` in `PHP`).

You should explicitly provide the set of columns you want to return, possibly aliasing them if the names match:

```
SELECT  users.username, users.surname,
        group_permissions.permission AS group_permission,
        users_permissions.permission AS users_permission
FROM    users
LEFT JOIN
        group_permissions
ON      group_permissions.group_id = users.group_id
LEFT JOIN
        users_permissions
ON      users_permissions.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE   users.username = 'admin'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination and example always helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

Uhn... How about using a `LEFT JOIN`...???

```
SELECT `*` FROM (`users`)
LEFT JOIN `group_permissions` ON `users`.`group_id` = `group_permissions`.`group_id`
LEFT JOIN `users_permissions` ON `users`.`user_id` = `users_permissions`.`user_id`
WHERE `users`.`username` = 'admin'
```

Comment: Correct. `JOIN` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN`, @dark, which only returns results in which a record exists on both sides of the join. A `LEFT` (or `RIGHT`) OUTER JOIN (the OUTER keyword is typically optional) will provide the results you seek.

Comment: @dark: Weird, I did't know MySQL had that kind of behavior. Anyway, which columns you DO care about? Instead of `SELECT *` you could use a `SELECT users.*` to fetch only fields from the `users` table, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`.

A very simply explanation of it's use is here: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

The fields from the table that may potentially not exist will return as `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most useful visualization of JOINs I've ever seen so I want to throw this out here, maybe it'll help someone: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Except that is actually visualization of `UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` :)